# How to do confusion matrix after bootstrapping for logistic regression in R?

Tags: r

I split my data into training and test set. I bootstrapped on my training set and I will need to conduct a validation test on my test set. How do I achieve this? Do I compare it via confusion matrix? If yes, can you guys please advise?

This is the share link to access the dataset:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=11LzPjH8RQraOI0eOYJRVRwgnRGL6Bnic

```
library(tidyverse)

library(caret)

mydata <- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/FYP/FYP2/data.csv")

# create training data
mydata_ones <- mydata[which(mydata$INJ_FAT == 1), ]
mydata_zeros <- mydata[which(mydata$INJ_FAT == 0), ]
set.seed(100) #for repeatability of samples

mydata_ones_training_rows <- sample(1:nrow(mydata_ones), 0.8*nrow(mydata_ones))
mydata_zeros_training_rows <- sample(1:nrow(mydata_zeros),0.8*nrow(mydata_zeros))

training_ones <- mydata_ones[mydata_ones_training_rows, ]
training_zeros <- mydata_zeros[mydata_zeros_training_rows, ]
train.data <- rbind(training_ones, training_zeros) # row bind the 1's and 0's
#print(trainingData)

# create test data
test_ones <- mydata_ones[-mydata_ones_training_rows, ]
test_zeros <- mydata_zeros[-mydata_zeros_training_rows, ]
test.data <- rbind(test_ones, test_zeros)

library(boot) 

x <- model.matrix(~., train.data)
logit.bootstrap <- function(data, indices) {

  d <- data[indices, ]
  fit <- glm(INJ_FAT~., data = d, family = "binomial")

  return(coef(fit))
}

set.seed(12345)
logit.boot <- boot(data=as.data.frame(x), statistic=logit.bootstrap, R=3500)
logit.boot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your boot function, you keep only the regression coefficients, so to do any kind of validation, you need to get back the predicted probability. First I run 10 bootstraps below, and note, you either use the model matrix or a formula and data.frame, but not both, in your code you will end with 2 intercepts:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

set.seed(100)
mydata <- read.csv("data.csv")
idx = createDataPartition(mydata$INJ_FAT,p=0.8)

train.data <- mydata[idx$Resample1,]
test.data <- mydata[-idx$Resample1,]

library(boot) 
set.seed(12345)
logit.boot <- boot(data=train.data, statistic=logit.bootstrap, R=10)
```

Your coefficients are stored here, 1 row for every bootstrap, every column is 1 cofficient:

```
head(logit.boot$t)
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     [,6]       [,7]
[1,] -4.271000 1.1001241 -1.4136104 -1.621620 -2.584495 5.374047  -2.691607
[2,] -5.048106 1.6833989 -0.2461192 -2.053468 -1.937496 5.608855  -2.415466
[3,] -8.152342 0.9078029 -1.2023567 -1.102740 -2.585418 5.462476  -2.304434
[4,] -6.254665 1.1466750 -0.5599730 -2.132731 -3.401947 4.939235 -17.332697
```

For 1 bootstrap, to get the prediction probability, you do:

```
logodds_to_pred = function(pred,levels){
ifelse(exp(pred)/(1+exp(pred))>0.5,levels[2],levels[1])
}

predictions_b1 = model.matrix(INJ_FAT~.,data=test.data) %*% logit.boot$t[1,]
# convert to 0/1, if prob > 0.5 it's 1 else 0
predictions_b1 = logodds_to_pred(predictions_b1,c(0,1))

confusionMatrix(table(predictions_b1,test.data$INJ_FAT))
Confusion Matrix and Statistics


predictions_b1   0   1
             0 544  27
             1  10  91

               Accuracy : 0.9449          
                 95% CI : (0.9249, 0.9609)
    No Information Rate : 0.8244          
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : < 2.2e-16       

                  Kappa : 0.7984          

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.008529
```

To collect it for all the bootstraps we do a matrix multiplication for all the boostraps:

```
logodds = model.matrix(INJ_FAT~.,data=test.data) %*% t(logit.boot$t)
predictions = apply(logodds,2,logodds_to_pred,level=c(0,1))
```

And for each bootstrap (column), we do the confusion matrix and get a summary:

```
results = lapply(1:ncol(predictions),function(i){
confusionMatrix(table(test.data$INJ_FAT,predictions[,i]))$overall
})

results[[1]]
      Accuracy          Kappa  AccuracyLower  AccuracyUpper   AccuracyNull 
  9.449405e-01   7.983978e-01   9.249033e-01   9.609404e-01   8.497024e-01 
AccuracyPValue  McnemarPValue 
  6.879023e-15   8.528852e-03
```

Not quite sure how you would consolidate your results over many bootstraps, but I guess with the above you can move on..